# Need to get dynamically created ID from jquery plugin Dyna Tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using a really nifty plugin call Dyna Tabs which is able to generate tabs dynamically, but I need to be able to get the ID of the newly created tab so that I can manipulate the content for that specific ID. Here is the function for how the tab is created:

```
$.addDynaTab({
tabID : 'addstatictab',
type : 'ajax',
url : 'ajaxcontent.html',
method : 'get',
dtype : 'html',
params : {},
tabTitle : 'New Ajax Tab'
});
```

Here is an example of the created tab, whose ID is "tabview_addstatictabbody4."

```
 <div id="tabview_addstatictabbody4" class="unselected" style="display: block;"><p>This HTML content is loaded statically</p></div>
```

How do I get/refer to this dynamically created ID using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it appends the div to another element?

Well let's pretend the parent is:

```
<div id="tabs"></div>
```

You could then possibly do:

```
$('#tabs div:last')
```

to get the last div element within "tabs"

If you need to store the ID's for future reference:

```
var TabId = new Array();
```

And on each load:

```
TabId[$('#tabs div').length - 1] = $('#tabs div:last').attr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This almost works. When I add a tab it works at first, but when I add an additional tab, the first tab stops updating. I suspect because the focus is now on the newly created tab. I think I need the actual ID name.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible resolution for storing the ID's

Comment: I'm sorry to bug you again. I have my reference to the array set up like this: `var TabId = new Array();               

                TabId[$('#addstatictabbody div').length - 1] = $('#addstatictabbody div:last').attr('id');` Then immediately following I reference the value in a function: `jQuery("#"+ TabId[$('#addstatictabbody div').length - 1]).everyTime(1000, function (i) { some code here }` Again,this function iterates through itself every second until certain conditions are met. Each iteration references the ID value. The new tab creation only works if I wait for first tab to complete.

Comment: I figured my particular problem. I needed to set the ID value as a local variable within the function the value was being called. So, `var tabID = TabId[$('#addstatictabbody div').length - 1];` It was breaking because the function was referencing the global value of the ID (just `TabId[$('#addstatictabbody div').length - 1]`), and so the first ID value was being replaced by the second. Thanks again for your help!